# Can we create pwa-app for asp.net .web forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, progressive-web-apps

I want to create a pwa with asp.net webforms.I am not able to understand how to register the service worker and how to make web app available for online.

Answer (score 12):

The short answer to your question is "Yes".

I have it up and running on my Web forms asp.net site.

Use Microsoft PWA Builder. Its super simple and will save you some time.
https://www.pwabuilder.com/

I did have to move my pwabuilder-sw.js to my root dir to get it working.
Sorry for the short answer here is a step by step. Please to read the comments in the code.

Step One: Create a manifest.json file -
You can find more info about web app Manifest files here:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest
& 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest

It will end up looking something like this :

```
{
  "name": "Longer Answer",
  "short_name": "Not a short answer",
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background_color": "#fff",
  "description": "A simply readable Longer Answer News app.",
  "icons": [{
    "src": "images/touch/homescreen48.png",
    "sizes": "48x48",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "images/touch/homescreen72.png",
    "sizes": "72x72",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "images/touch/homescreen96.png",
    "sizes": "96x96",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "images/touch/homescreen144.png",
    "sizes": "144x144",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "images/touch/homescreen168.png",
    "sizes": "168x168",
    "type": "image/png"
  }, {
    "src": "images/touch/homescreen192.png",
    "sizes": "192x192",
    "type": "image/png"
  }]      
}
```

Step two: create a service worker. A Service workers can make your site work offline, run faster, or both. The following example will be an advanced caching service worker which allows you to configure files and routes that are cached in different manners (pre-cache, server first, cache first, etc.). The script can be used to build a lightening fast app (even for dynamic content) that works offline. More info on Service Workers here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers

File name: register-sw.js

```
// This is the "Offline page" service worker

// Add this below content to your HTML page, or add the js file to your page at the very top to register service worker

// Check compatibility for the browser we're running this in
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
    console.log("[PWA Builder] active service worker found, no need to register");
  } else {
    // Register the service worker
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register("pwabuilder-sw.js", {
        scope: "./"
      })
      .then(function (reg) {
        console.log("[PWA Builder] Service worker has been registered for scope: " + reg.scope);
      });
  }
}
```

File name: pwa-sw.js

```
//This is the service worker with the Advanced caching

const CACHE = "pwabuilder-adv-cache";
const precacheFiles = [
  /* Add an array of files to precache for your app */
];

// TODO: replace the following with the correct offline fallback page i.e.: const offlineFallbackPage = "offline.html";
const offlineFallbackPage = "ToDo-replace-this-name.html";

const networkFirstPaths = [
  /* Add an array of regex of paths that should go network first */
  // Example: /\/api\/.*/
];

const avoidCachingPaths = [
  /* Add an array of regex of paths that shouldn't be cached */
  // Example: /\/api\/.*/
];

function pathComparer(requestUrl, pathRegEx) {
  return requestUrl.match(new RegExp(pathRegEx));
}

function comparePaths(requestUrl, pathsArray) {
  if (requestUrl) {
    for (let index = 0; index < pathsArray.length; index++) {
      const pathRegEx = pathsArray[index];
      if (pathComparer(requestUrl, pathRegEx)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}

self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
  console.log("[PWA] Install Event processing");

  console.log("[PWA] Skip waiting on install");
  self.skipWaiting();

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
      console.log("[PWA] Caching pages during install");

      return cache.addAll(precacheFiles).then(function () {
        if (offlineFallbackPage === "ToDo-replace-this-name.html") {
          return cache.add(new Response("TODO: Update the value of the offlineFallbackPage constant in the serviceworker."));
        }

        return cache.add(offlineFallbackPage);
      });
    })
  );
});

// Allow sw to control of current page
self.addEventListener("activate", function (event) {
  console.log("[PWA] Claiming clients for current page");
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

// If any fetch fails, it will look for the request in the cache and serve it from there first
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  if (event.request.method !== "GET") return;

  if (comparePaths(event.request.url, networkFirstPaths)) {
    networkFirstFetch(event);
  } else {
    cacheFirstFetch(event);
  }
});

function cacheFirstFetch(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fromCache(event.request).then(
      function (response) {
        // The response was found in the cache so we responde with it and update the entry

        // This is where we call the server to get the newest version of the
        // file to use the next time we show view
        event.waitUntil(
          fetch(event.request).then(function (response) {
            return updateCache(event.request, response);
          })
        );

        return response;
      },
      function () {
        // The response was not found in the cache so we look for it on the server
        return fetch(event.request)
          .then(function (response) {
            // If request was success, add or update it in the cache
            event.waitUntil(updateCache(event.request, response.clone()));

            return response;
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            // The following validates that the request was for a navigation to a new document
            if (event.request.destination !== "document" || event.request.mode !== "navigate") {
              return;
            }

            console.log("[PWA] Network request failed and no cache." + error);
            // Use the precached offline page as fallback
            return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
              cache.match(offlineFallbackPage);
            });
          });
      }
    )
  );
}

function networkFirstFetch(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request)
      .then(function (response) {
        // If request was success, add or update it in the cache
        event.waitUntil(updateCache(event.request, response.clone()));
        return response;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("[PWA ] Network request Failed. Serving content from cache: " + error);
        return fromCache(event.request);
      })
  );
}

function fromCache(request) {
  // Check to see if you have it in the cache
  // Return response
  // If not in the cache, then return error page
  return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
    return cache.match(request).then(function (matching) {
      if (!matching || matching.status === 404) {
        return Promise.reject("no-match");
      }

      return matching;
    });
  });
}

function updateCache(request, response) {
  if (!comparePaths(request.url, avoidCachingPaths)) {
    return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
      return cache.put(request, response);
    });
  }

  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Step three: Test to make sure your new manifest.json file and scripts are working.

I know of two ways to test your pwa configs:

1. open up google dev tool and go to the applications tab. Then on the left had side click on Service Workers. Next check the box towards the top "Update on reload". After that reload your page and watch for the results.
2. Audit the site using lighthouse. You can find that in the google developer tools under the Audits tab.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: you need a long answer, as it is, your answer is not acceptable

Answer (score -5):

The short answer to your question is "No".

Just have a SPA (Single Page Application) launch your service worker and also call back to your .Net controllers to get what data/functionality is needed.

No Razor,web-forms etc.

NB: If anyone advises you to use React-Redux run away from them as quickly as you can! That is first hand advice but I'm sure the same can be said for Angular and Vue.

Comment: Just curious why not?