# Using PWA in ASPNET Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, progressive-web-apps

I have an old project that use aspnet webform,how can I use PWA in it?
the second is Can I use the PWA in website without ssl?

I used pwa in aspnet core,and I Know how to implement it by using manifest.json file and installing [pwa nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.PWA/),however I don't know how to use in my old project

Comment: PWA is intend to use a Service Worker and Push Notifications, so HTTPS is required

Comment: @vailily.sib that's right,thanks

Comment: this link can help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53062150/can-we-create-pwa-app-for-asp-net-web-forms

Comment: searching about serviceWorker can help to implent it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can , there is some steps to make it .
use this site its explained step by step [PWA](https://sokanacademy.com/blog/10396/progressive-web-app)

and you should have ssl for your website.it's not work without ssl.